# Exponentiating columns of a data frame inside a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have multiple data frames in a list l and a vector of numbers with the same length as l

```
set.seed(222)
a <- data.frame(x=rnorm(6), y=rnorm(6), z=rnorm(6))
b <- data.frame(x=rnorm(6), y=rnorm(6), z=rnorm(6))
c <- data.frame(x=rnorm(6), y=rnorm(6), z=rnorm(6))
l <- list(a, b, c)
v <- c(1:3)
```

I now want to exponentiate the first y column inside l by the power of 1, the second by the power of 2 and the third by the power of 3 preferentially using apply but a for loop would also be OK.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
lapply(l, function(df) as.data.frame(t(t(df)^v)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
Map(`^`, l, list(v[col(l[[1]])]))
```

or

```
Map(function(x,y) mapply(`^`, x,y), l, list(v))
```